# React: get data attribute from datalist option onchange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jsx

Ok, none of the existing solutions here work, so...

How do I get the data attribute from a datalist in React (no from a select)?

**Render JSX**

```js
<input list="list-id" id="input-id" multiple onChange={handleInputChange} />
<datalist id="list-id">
    {
        options.map((item, key) => {
            return <option key={key} data-foo={item.id} value={item.value}>{item.name}</option>;
        })
    }
</datalist>
```

**Event handler**

```js
function handleInputChange(e) {
    console.dir(e.target.dataset)                    // Empty DOMStringMap
    console.dir(e.target.getAttribute('data-foo'))   // null
    console.dir(e.target.attributes)                 // NamedNodeMap with no option
    console.dir(e.target.options)                    // undefined
}
```

I've managed in other Vanilla JS cases to get the value like this...

```js
let inputValue = document.getElementById("input-id").value;
let option = document.querySelector(`option[value="${inputValue}"]`).getAttribute('data-foo');
```

Which would be used like this in React...

```js
function getDatalistSelectedOption(inputId, attribute) {
    let inputValue = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
    let option = document.querySelector(`option[value="${inputValue}"]`);
    let optionValue = option ? option.getAttribute(attribute) : "";
    return optionValue
}

// In the event handler
console.log(getDatalistSelectedOption("input-id", "data-foo")) // returns the proper data value
```

But it doesn't seem like the proper way in React.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It seems like you're missing the main benefits of React.

Comment: Well, I want to save the option ID in the database, not the selected option value. Let's say a product has an SKU of `p0001` and the name is `product 123`, while the ID is `1234`. I want to save `1234` behind the scenes, without the user seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd never use this myself, because there are way better packages online ([react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select)). However if you want to use the data-list, then you could get the data attribute of the selected value like this:

```
function handleInputChange() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("input-id").value;
    var options = document.getElementById("list-id").childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
      if (options[i].value === inputValue) {

        // Send to DB - options[i].attributes.value

        console.log(options[i].attributes.value)
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```